# How to link a Facebook authentication while Google authentication already exist for Firebase in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm facing problem for Firebase linking authentication!

I can successfully do:

1. signing with Facebook account, and firebase shown Facebook's authentication
2. sign out Facebook account and sign in with google account, while linked both accounts by this codes:

   ```
   if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
       user.link(with: credential) { (user, error) in
   } }
   ```

These work totally fine!

However, if I do reversely:

1. signing with Google account, and firebase shown Google's authentication
2. sign out Google account and sign in with Facebook account

I got an error as follow:

> An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.

Is there any solutions?